# sum of all properties of node in gremlin

Tags: graph, aggregate, gremlin, janusgraph

Considering three nodes in a graph with 3 properties want to calculate the sum of each property for all the nodes using the gremlin query.

```
g.addV('node').property('property1',1).property('property2',2).property('property3',3).next()
g.addV('node').property('property1',4).property('property2',5).property('property3',6).next()
g.addV('node').property('property1',7).property('property2',8).property('property3',9).next()
```

Output:
The required output is the sum of respective properties for all nodes using the gremlin query.
property1: 12, property2: 15, property3: 18

Answer (score 3):

```
g.V().hasLabel('node').
  properties('property1', 'property2', 'property3').
  group().by(key).
    by(value().sum())
```

Here's a live example: https://gremlify.com/t0jy5i6hkh8/2

Comment: there are 300k nodes for which the aggregation has to be done. The properties step is taking around 80% of the total time. Need to optimize the query. Any suggestion, how can it be done.